# Foundation 5 Top Bar Dropdown on click not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation, haml

I can't get my top bar dropdown to work on click.  It works fine on hover though (if I add the "not-click" class to my li.has-dropdown).  Although, I need my dropdown to only be accessible on click only.  I've read a number of other posts related to this and I am sure I'm doing the following:

1.) I believe I am correctly initializing foundation with $(document).foundation(); in my application.js.

2.) I also am including foundation/foundation.js and then foundation/foundation.topbar.js (amoung other plugins) in my header.  I have not included foundation/foundation.min.js.

3.) I'm using UI-router to generate my url for the link to my Stuff page.  I pretty sure this has something to do with why this isn't working.  You'll notice I tried doing a e.preventDefault() in my "ng-init" at the top to try and get the click event to register for my dropdown.  This will prevent the default event from happening on all of my "a" tags.

I want to be able to go to the "Stuff" page when I click on any other part of my "a" Stuff link other than the dropdown arrow.
Clicking on the dropdown arrow should open the dropdown, but not go to the "Stuff" page.
Currently, no matter where I click on the "a" Stuff link I am directed to the Stuff page, even when click on the dropdown arrow, and there is no dropdown displayed.

Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
%nav.top-bar{"data-topbar" => true, "ng-controller" => "HeaderController", 
"ng-init"   => "preventDefault();", :data => {:options => "is_hover: false"}}
  %section.top-bar-section.row
    %ul
      %li.section.divider.has-dropdown.small-12{"ng-class" => "{ active :  isActive('/deals')}", 
"ng-controller" => "StuffController"}
        %a{"ui-sref" => "{{state})'}}"}
          Stuff
        %ul.dropdown
          %li{"ng-repeat" => "stuff in stuffs"}
            %a
              {{ stuff.name }}
```

Comment: Hello, did you get solution for this ?
I think it's definitively ui-router that is blocking the expected behaviour, may dropdown were working untill I had the lib ...